# sticky footer with simplesidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a [sidebar I'm using from startbootstrap](https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap/tree/gh-pages/templates/simple-sidebar). I'm trying to add a sticky footer to the bottom of the page. When I toggle the navbar though the footer jumps up to the top.

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-class="{'toggled': hidden }">
  <div ng-include='"views/nav.html"'></div>
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row" id='main-body'>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div ui-view=''></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <footer id='sticky-footer'>
        <p class='text-muted'>The source for this website is <a href='http://github.com/jasonshark/jasonshark.github.io'>available on Github</a></p>
      </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where `nav.html` looks like:

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="/">Connor Leech</a></li>
        <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref='resume'>Resume</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref='portfolio'>Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref='timeline'>Timeline</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<button class='btn btn-default btn-lg inverse' ng-click='hideMenu()'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify'></span>
</button>
```

I added these styles to move the footer to the bottom:

```
#sticky-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here are the styles that toggle the sidebar:

```
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}
```

There's a little bit of angular.js that adds or removes the `.toggled` class when we click the menu. How can I keep the footer stuck to the bottom even when the nav menu slides to the left?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

Use position fixed for sticky-footer instead of absolute, I don't have your code loaded but that is probably it.

Taken from http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Fixed Positioning: An element with fixed position is positioned relative to the browser window.

Absolute Positioning: An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is :